# ADD content-Type in postgres request?

Tags: postgresql, url, elasticsearch, service, content-type

I want use elasticsearch via zombodb extension so I use this query  in postgres : `CREATE INDEX idx_zdb_graduated ON masterview USING zombodb(zdb('masterview', masterview.ctid), zdb(masterview)) WITH (url='http://localhost:9200/'
);`
but it has a this error

```
> ERROR:  rc=406; {"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}
```

I googled and i found that i should use -H'Content-Type:application/json' if I use curl to connect to elasticsearch . but i don't know how  can I add content-type to my query ?

Comment: You should probably raise an issue about it in the [zombodb repo](https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb)

Comment: Hi.  Please report this to ZomboDB's github project at https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb/ and I'll help you.  Please include PG, ES, and ZDB versions along with your table definition.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use unsupported version's elastic search or postgresql or os.
I had same error with elastisearh version than 6 and fix it to version.
 [In my git repository](https://github.com/tkow/test-zombodb), with debian 9, postgres:9.5, and elasticsearch:5.6.4 should work.